Creating a bat file to force close microsoft excel
First of all, i am sorry if i post this in a wrong community as i am new to this.
So i am trying to run a bat file whenever something goes wrong, the code for the bat file is as follows:
taskkill /IM iexplore.exe /f
taskkill /IM excel.exe /f
taskkill /IM chrome.exe /f
taskkill /IM msedge.exe /f

When i tested it, it runs well even if there is a "prompt/warning windows", etc. However the issue appears in a different environment whenever there is some new window in the excel, for example "Large Operation windows in Excel", "A Warning about data does not exist", or like when you are sorting or searching something that does not exist, the excel will then gave a prompt/warning window, etc. the bat file doesn't actually close the excel
What i wanted to have is, whatever windows that came from that excel is also closed along with the excel. I do not know whether this is excel settings which is probably not based on my last check.
Thanks in Advance

This sounds so much like an X-Y problem. You have an issue, and you came up with an idea to solve it, and now you're having problem making that solution. While we could of course assist you with that, if you tell us why you need this in the first place, we may be able to come up with a solution that works far better. I mean, if you have a problem with your sink not draining properly, and your solution is to drill a bigger hole, ours would be to call a plumber.

I am running a software, an automation to be exact and whenever it goes to the error handler it will then run the batch file. Tested it in the development environment all works good, but when it is running in the production environment it keeps failing to close the excel as there is sometimes a prompt/error window. i did use /f in the batch file to force it but i do not understand why it keeps failing to close the excel. My best bet is because i am not an admin which is why it's happening, but i am open to discuss or solve it using another way

What is the automation supposed to do?

It does some excel automation for reporting, we cannot use excel macro to be clear.

Why can't you use excel macros? That doesn't make sense.

because there are some policies which i don't get as i am not involved in the requirement process. this also includes some other internal websites which should be why they are using the automation process. anyway the process can be done from end to end, it just sometimes the error handler doesn't work to the fullest as an error/prompt window from excel appears and can't be closed using the batch file above.  Rather than a batch file command/code is there any idea to close the excel when an error/prompt window is opened? or maybe any other solution
